# Invalid use of Null: CDate() after server change IP address

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

There is a server in my company and today it changed IP Addresses, after that my website would not work well.

`CDate()` will not work, it shows

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a005e'
>   Invalid use of Null: 'cdate'

here is my code :

```
<%if cdate(now())-cdate(myrs("call_time"))>7 and cdate(now())-cdate(myrs("call_time"))<=14 then%>bgcolor="#FFEAEA"<%end if%><%if cdate(now())-cdate(myrs("call_time"))>14 then%>bgcolor="#FF8080"<%end if%>>
```

Comment: The error is actually rather self-explanatory: you called `CDate` with a parameter that is `Null`. As to *why* that parameter is `Null`: well, we wouldn't know without actually seeing your code.

Comment: <tr <%if cdate(now())-cdate(myrs("call_time"))>7 and cdate(now())-cdate(myrs("call_time"))<=14 then%>bgcolor="#FFEAEA"<%end if%><%if cdate(now())-cdate(myrs("call_time"))>14 then%>bgcolor="#FF8080"<%end if%>> here is my code , thanks !

Comment: `CDate(Now)` is unlikely to produce the error, so check the value of `myrs("call_time")`.

Comment: It can work right now and what make me confused is that I have done nothing on it !

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the value that you're passing into the `CDate()` function like so:

```vb
If IsDate(myDateVar) Then
    myOtherDate = CDate(myDateVar)
End If
```